# Insane crond behavior. keeps making defunct bash processes

Tags: php, bash, centos, cron

I have a crontab that looks like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

0-59 * * * * /var/www/html/private/fivemin/zdaemon.php >> /dev/null &
```

Simple as possible, right?

zdaemon.php which I am just testing with is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?


while(true){
        sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Whenever it runs it hangs like:

```
root     15532  0.0  0.1 57228 1076 ?        Ss   19:09   0:00 crond
root     16681  0.0  0.1 72196 1428 ?        S    21:46   0:00 crond
root     16682  0.0  0.0     0    0 ?        Zs   21:46   0:00 [bash] <defunct>
root     16683  0.0  0.5 54800 5740 ?        S    21:46   0:00 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/private/fivemin/zdaemon.php
root     16687  0.0  0.1 72196 1428 ?        S    21:47   0:00 crond
root     16688  0.0  0.0     0    0 ?        Zs   21:47   0:00 [bash] <defunct>
root     16689  0.0  0.5 54800 5740 ?        S    21:47   0:00 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/private/fivemin/zdaemon.php
```

I have been banging my brain against a wall on this all day. Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas at all?

This is a reference to: [Init.d script hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589786/init-d-script-hanging)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *zombie* process is not necessarily a bad thing in itself. It indicates that the *child* process has died, and the *parent* process has not yet reaped its status (using `wait()` or a related system call).

What is happening is as follows - `cron` is interested in *stderr* from the script it starts (so that it can email it to you should the script fail), therefore it creates a *pipe* which is attaches *stderr* of the script to write end (file descriptor 2). Then `cron` sits reading on the read end of the pipe, waiting for the script to exit and read *eof* (`read()` of zero bytes) - it then reaps the return status of the script.

In your example, the daemon spawned, inherits the *stderr* file descriptor, and therefore when the intermediate shell exits (and becomes defunct), the pipe is held open by the daemon. Therefore `cron` never reads *eof* and hence never reaps the return status.

The solution is to ensure that *stderr* of your daemon is closed. This can be achieved as follows:

```
0-59 * * * * /var/www/html/private/fivemin/zdaemon.php >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

which will write **both** *stdout* and *stderr* to `/dev/null`

Comment: This is perfect!! It was 100% stderr that was screwing me up. I changed the line to: $LDIR/$EXEC &> $LDIR/swapi.log & MYPID=$! in my init.d script (see other posting) and now it all works as it should. Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think your main problem is that the stderr is still going to the shell but the child process (your php process) is sleeping, resulting in the zombie process. Try this:

```
0-59 * * * * /var/www/html/private/fivemin/zdaemon.php &> /dev/null &
```

If you're still having problems with a zombie process, take a look at [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd to me to background a process in a crontab. Try removing the `&` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to create a daemon is to fork a child process to do the work, then exit the parent process with an error code of 0. I don't know for sure that this is your problem, though.

I haven't done this in php, but you could use [pcntl_fork()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to mimic [the usual c way](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html).

Comment: it should be noted that starting a daemon with fork() is not trivial, and you usually have to fork twice to do it right.